# Copy rectangular selection in web browser from HTML <pre> element with numerous nested levels of <span> descendants?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textselection, pre

I have HTML `<pre>` elements containing 160 columns by 62 rows of text; terminal screen captures, set in a monospace font. The text is marked-up by various `<span>` elements; for example, to set text color, background color, font weight, underlining; and also class names that encapsulate meta data about the content,
not necessarily display attributes. The `<span>` elements can be nested to arbitrary levels.

I want a "cropped" version of that original 160x62 `<pre>` element; a rectangular selection from the original, retaining the `<span>` markup.

I don't want to capture the rectangular selection as a bitmapped screenshot. I want to keep the content as HTML.

In a web browser, I want to marquee-select a rectangular area of text in the original 160x62 `<pre>` element, and then get a `<pre>` element that represents that "crop" area (for example, 30x30; whatever the dimensions of the selection might be).

**The cropped `<pre>` must preserve all of the formatting, all of the "active" `<span>` elements, of that area in the  original `<pre>`.**

For each row of the selected rectangular area, the software that creates the cropped `<pre>` must recognize which `<span>` elements are open in the original `<pre>` at the left edge of the cropped area, and start the appropriate set of `<span>` elements to reproduce that "context".

Ideally, there is existing software to do this that I have overlooked, and the answer to this question is simply a link to that software (e.g. in-browser JavaScript).

Otherwise, what's a good technique for performing a character-by-character rectangular selection of text in a `<pre>` element displayed in a web browser, that provides the start and end coordinates (column and row numbers) of the selection in the `<pre>`?

I've seen browser extensions that *highlight* a rectangular selection in a web browser, but none that do what I've described here.

I'm comfortable writing JavaScript that explores the DOM. Given character-based coordinates of a rectangular selection (row and column numbers inside the original `<pre>`), I reckon I could write the code to create the cropped `<pre>`, starting and ending the necessary "active"/antecedent `<span>` elements on each row of the selection. I'm less sure how to perform the character-by-character marquee selection of the `<pre>` contents, though. I'd prefer to be told "It's been done, here". Advice welcome.

Comment: Asking for libraries is OT here; you should try to write this yourself and if you get stuck, ask for help instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround: embed the HTML `<pre>` in an SVG `<foreignObject>`

In case this is useful to anyone else: I've developed a workaround that achieves a cropped view without actually cropping the `<pre>` markup. No code libraries involved. Just markup.

I acknowledge that, strictly speaking, this is not a direct answer to my original question. But it achieves the effect I want.

The workaround: embed the HTML `<pre>` element in an SVG `<foreignObject>` element inside an `<svg>` element. Adjust the SVG `viewBox` to show only the area that you want.

I've elided a lot of detail (e.g. calculating the `viewBox` values based on details such as number of rows and columns, and the font aspect ratio), but that's the basic idea.